# HTTP Status 500 - javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Exception creating bean of class

Tags: maven, servlets, struts-1

Hi i'm trying to create a simple form validation using maven struts 1.3 dependencies but i m getting the following error in my web page

HTTP Status 500 - javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Exception creating bean of class amit.form.LoginForm under form name loginForm

```
type Exception report

message javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Exception creating bean of class amit.form.LoginForm under form name loginForm

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Exception creating bean of class amit.form.LoginForm under form name loginForm
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:555)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:461)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Exception creating bean of class amit.form.LoginForm under form name loginForm
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:909)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:838)
    org.apache.jsp.login_jsp._jspService(login_jsp.java:154)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

root cause

javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Exception creating bean of class amit.form.LoginForm under form name loginForm
    org.apache.struts.taglib.html.FormTag.initFormBean(FormTag.java:536)
    org.apache.struts.taglib.html.FormTag.doStartTag(FormTag.java:503)
    org.apache.jsp.login_jsp._jspx_meth_html_005fform_005f0(login_jsp.java:174)
    org.apache.jsp.login_jsp._jspService(login_jsp.java:138)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

here is all my code

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.maven</groupId>
<artifactId>StrutsWebApp</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>StrutsWebApp Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts-taglib</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.10</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
<finalName>StrutsWebApp</finalName>
</build>
</project>
```

struts-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.3//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-config_1_3.dtd">

<struts-config>
<form-beans>
    <form-bean name="loginForm" type="amit.form.LoginForm" />
</form-beans>
<action-mappings>
    <action name="loginForm" path="/login"
        type="amit.action.LoginAction" scope="request"
        input="/login.jsp">
        <forward name="failure" path="/login.jsp" redirect="true" />
        <forward name="success" path="/success.jsp" redirect="true" />
    </action>
</action-mappings>
</struts-config>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>LoginFormStruts</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>config</param-name>
        <param-value>
      /WEB-INF/struts-config.xml
   </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

login.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" prefix="html"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Login Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<html:form action="/login" focus="userName">
Username : <html:text property="userName" />
    <br>
Password : <html:password property="password" />
    <br>
    <html:submit value="login" />
</html:form>
</body>
</html>
```

success.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Welcome Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello JavaWebTutor</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

LoginAction.java

```
package amit.action;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.struts.action.Action;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForward;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping;

import amit.forms.LoginForm;

public class LoginAction extends Action {
@Override
public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception {
    System.out.println("hello");
    LoginForm loginForm = (LoginForm) form;

    if (loginForm.getUserName() == null || loginForm.getPassword() == null
            || !loginForm.getUserName().equalsIgnoreCase("Mukesh")
            || !loginForm.getPassword().equals("kumar")) {
        return mapping.findForward("failure");
    } else
        return mapping.findForward("success");
}

}
```

LoginForm.java

```
package amit.forms;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping;

public class LoginForm extends ActionForm {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String userName = null;
private String password = null;

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

@Override
public void reset(ActionMapping mapping, HttpServletRequest request) {
    this.password = null;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You have mentioned wrong package name in type attribute of form-bean tag. It  should be amit.forms.LoginForm

<form-beans>
    <form-bean name="loginForm" type="amit.forms.LoginForm" />
</form-beans>
```

Comment: i dont know how i did that silly mistake thanks for your help @WZee